# How to construct depth map with stereo vision if the extrinsic and intrinsic matrixes are unknown?

Tags: computer-vision, vision, pose-estimation

**Task:** Given 2 images from 2 different cameras, construct a depth map from the point of view of the 1st camera. The cameras are not calibrated, so the extrinsic and intrinsic matrices are unknown. We know that the cameras are in slightly different positions (eg. I take a photo, move the camera a bit and take another one). No fancy library shall be used, mostly a self-implemented solution.

**My idea:**

1. Detect some keypoints on both of the images
2. Do some correspondence matching on the keypoints, so we will have a bunch of keypoint pairs, that are likely to represent the same point on both of the images
3. Use Bundle Adjustment to find the extrinsic and intrinsic matrices
4. Calculate the fundamental matrix from the extrinsic and intrinsic matrices
5. For every pixel on the first image, search through the epipolar line on the second image (with the help of the fundamental matrix) and find matching locations
6. For every matched pair, calculate the two rays (lines) corresponding to the two points.
7. Ideally, they would intersect, but if not, calculate the point on the first line, that is closest to the second line.
8. The distance of that point from the camera itself should give depth information.
9. Do the last few steps for every point and then we have a depth map.

**Questions:**

1. Would this approach work?
2. IMO, it seems a bit complicated, are there any easier approaches?
3. Could I avoid somehow doing the Bundle Adjustment? Eg. Just calculating the fundamental matrix with 8bits is easier, but I don't see how would that be enough.
4. (Is this the right place to ask this?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are really interested in this subject, do yourself a favor and get a good book. I warmly recommend [H&S MVICV](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/multiple-view-geometry-in-computer-vision/0B6F289C78B2B23F596CAA76D3D43F7A). There is an entire field of computer vision, image processing and vision geometry that you asking about, and cannot possibly be covered in a SO answer.

After you have read (at least) up to the chapter on two-view geometry, you will have some understanding of the problem, and will very likely want to use an existing library to do some of the tasks involved. Writing good triangulation code, for example, is highly nontrivial.

Best of luck and happy new year.